# Routing Error uninitialized constant UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am working on a tutorial to learn Rails development.

I apologize if this question is redundant. It may be that my beginner experience level made it difficult to find a relevant existing answer.

Any help is truly appreciated.

The object of the lesson is to build a Reddit-like site. In this lesson, I am supposed to implement image uploading utilizing S3 storage with the CarrierWave and MiniMagick gems. As far as I can tell I have closely followed the lesson's instructions, but maybe I'm missing something.

When I try to upload an image file from the edit view, this is what happens.

Here is the error:

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:5:in `update'


Rendered /Users/gregorybowler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (8.5ms)
Rendered /Users/gregorybowler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.5ms)
Rendered /Users/gregorybowler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.4ms)
Rendered /Users/gregorybowler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (64.7ms)
Cannot render console with content type multipart/form-dataAllowed content types: [#<Mime::Type:0x007fd34a40cb10 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html">, #<Mime::Type:0x007fd34a40ce30 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:text, @string="text/plain">, #<Mime::Type:0x007fd3493e8d88 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:url_encoded_form, @string="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">]


Started PATCH "/users/8" for ::1 at 2015-07-03 22:05:20 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UsersController):
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
```

Here is my user_controller.rb file:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

def update
  if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:notice] = "User information updated"
    redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
  else
    flash[:error] = "Invalid user information"
    redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
  end
end

 private

 def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name, :avatar)
 end
end
```

Here is config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:update]

resources :topics do
  resources :posts, except: [:index]
end

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

  root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was frowning for a good 10 minutes when I came across it. The error indicates that it's not finding your `UsersController` constant, which is your class.

You said it was at `user_controller.rb`. However Rails autoloading would only expect to find `UsersController`, note the 's', in, you guessed it, `app/controllers/users_controller.rb`. (Good to remember that convention dictates that `#{thing}Controller` is plural)

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I had a feeling that might be the culprit as I am aware of the convention, and I had wondered how I might refactor my code or file names to correct the issue. However, when I change the file name to users_controller.rb I get a new error that I don't understand: `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2588ms (ActiveRecord: 11.2ms)

Excon::Errors::BadRequest (Expected(200) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request)
excon.error.response`. Sorry if this is a naive response. I'm not sure how to fix.

Comment: @user2860664 Looks like we found the answer to this question, and you got a separate problem. Sounds like it's with your S3 upload and Carrierwave.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was indeed correct. The other issue was a secondary problem, which I fixed by changing my s3 region.